# Will Microsoft Azure charge me after FREE TRIAL ends?

Tags: azure, cloud

I have a free Azure account but now I have decided to never use it again. Will I be charged even after the trial period ends.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a billing question; not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the trial period, Microsoft will notify you and you'll have to decide whether you want to upgrade your subscription to a 'pay-as-you-go' pricing model and remove the spending limit. If you do, you’ll have access to free products. If you don’t, your account and products will be disabled, and you’ll need to upgrade to resume usage.

Having access to the free products ([see the full list here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/free/)), note that you won't be charged if you respect the quotas specified for the free products but you will be charged for extra consumption or for using services that are not part of the free products offer.

I hope this makes sense.